# Explicit diffeomorphism between two models of hyperbolic 3-space

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking for an explicit diffeomorphism between the matrix model  and the homogeneous space model of hyperbolic 3-space. Since all models are isometric, this must exist.

Here, I define the matrix model as $\mathbb{H}^3=\{H\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})|\ H\ hermitian\ \}$, the other as $\mathbb{H}^3=SO(3,\mathbb{C})/SO(3,\mathbb{R})$.

My first idea was to use the adjoint representation of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ into its lie algebra and thereby get a map into $SO(3,\mathbb{C})$. Unfortunately, the matrix model doesn't map injectively under this map, as for $A\in \mathbb{H}^3$ we also have $-A\in \mathbb{H}^3$.

Comment: Try to define an action of $\text{SO}(3, \mathbb{C})$ on the first model and compute its stabilizer.

Comment: I did try this, but to no avail. I fear I lack familitarity with the various geometric meanings of the models. Are there any references to read up on hyperbolic space and how the various models are constructed?

Comment: Okay, I forgot that PSL(2,C) is isomorphic to SO(3,C) with the very morphism I wanted to consider first. Since PSL(2,C) acts on $\mathbb{H}^3$, so does SO(3,C). Choosing the matrix with i and -i in the antidiagonal, we get what we want. Thank you!